# php ssh read output issue

Tags: php, linux, ssh, centos

I have a problem with the output of my php ssh script. I have this script

```
    $ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX); 
$ssh->write("$domainpath\n");
$ssh->setTimeout(5);
$ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX); 
$ssh->write("ls \n");
$domainlist = $ssh->read(NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX); 
echo $domainlist;
```

the problem is not that there is not enaything being put out but with the way it is presented.

```
ls [0m[00;33myourdomain.net[0m [00;33mdefault.domain[0m [00;33mtestdomain.com[0m [m[root@vps web]#
```

As you can see, the folders that i am getting back from the server is looking weird and terrible to load into an array.

How do i get a clean and nice output. Or is this control panel related? if there is the case and i can change it i can use a explode to clean it up.

thanks

Comment: That's a broken `ls` alias most likely. It sounds like `ls` is aliased to `ls --color=always` instead of just `ls --color` or similar. You can try `ls --color=never` to compensate for that but fixing the alias/etc. is likely a more correct approach.

Comment: @EtanReisner Changing the alias may not be preferred if the system is used or he ever needs to SSH in directly. Specifying no color via the PHP command or changing the alias for the PHP user only would seem best.

I know I like my colors if I have to SSH in.

Comment: but how can i keep it from putting it out to my php script. Something like that what i can strip it from the output.

Comment: the colornever works as it should, but would also be good to get rid of the complete command line.

Comment: @ToothlessRebel No, an alias of `ls --color=always` is simply incorrect. It isn't a sane default as evidenced by this problem. Using "auto" either implicitly (`--color`) or explicitly (`--color=auto`) is a **vastly** better default alias as it doesn't break these sorts of usage and still allows manual overriding in either direction, with `--color=never` and `--color=always` added manually.

Comment: @EtanReisner You are most likely correct. My point was that in some way he could configure it so that he doesn't have to disable color or always add `--color` to his own commands. I am curious what distro or image he is using to have it aliased as such, if it is.

Comment: A default alias of `ls --color` is perfectly reasonable and will use color at a terminal and not when sent to a pipe or other non-interactive environment... I suppose the php ssh session could be confusing the `ls` color detection code but I wouldn't assume that would be the case by default.

Answer (score 0):

Those strange characters are ANSI escape codes. You can filter them out using `File_ANSI` as described here:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#top